# How do I upgrade Zend framework 2.0.0 to 2.0.3 on windows?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2.0.0 and want to upgrade it to new version ZF 2.0.3

Is there any way to upgrade it?

Comment: Given your question `Is there any way to upgrade it?` I'd say that the most proper answer is `Yes, there is` and you most likely find it in zend framework docs.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be migrated.  Not closed.  It is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the 2.0.3 Version from Github and replace your `vendor\zendframework` folder manually or run `php composer.phar update` from your project root.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I did this and it works.